# In Spring how do you get the current user whose credentials are not part of the current http request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, authentication

Is there a "`getCurrentUser`" method in Spring to access the user that is currently part of a request - even if that user's name is not being passed around as part of a web request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question with spring-security I assume your question is in same context. With spring-security you can retrieve current user as :

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
UserDetails userDetails = null;
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
  userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
}
String userName = userDetails.getUsername();
```

Comment: Also Spring Security exposes its authentication data via `HttpServletRequest.getPrincipal()`.

Comment: this does not work for me getAuthentication() returns null, even though user is logged in http://stackoverflow.com/q/7811200/106261